# Mapping of $w=-z^2$ transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The next semester I'll be taking a math class where I'll learn about complex variable, so I'm starting to learn by myself the foundations. I have a couple of old homeworks from the past courses and I'm trying to answer them. I was attempting to do this question:

"Find and graph the region on the plane $w=u+iv$ delimited by the lines $x=1$, $y=1$ and $x+y=1$ using the transformation $w=-z^2$."

Well, the first thing I did was to determine what $u$ and $v$ are considering $z=x+iy$.

$$\begin{align*}
w &= -z^2=-(x+iy)^2\\
  &= -(x^2+2xyi-y^2)=\underbrace{y^2-x^2}_{u}+\underbrace{(-2xy)}_{v}i
\end{align*}$$

Hence I have

$$
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ccl}
u(x,y) & = & y^2-x^2\\
v(x,y) & = & -2xy
\end{array}\right.$$

Here I got a little confused. I have seen here other examples where it is given a certain value of $y$ and the recommendation is trying to eliminate either $x$ or $y$, but in this case, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any type of direction will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Find the image of the boundary first. If the line $x + y = 1$ is parametrized as $(t, 1 - t)$, the image is $(u, v) = (1 - 2 t, 2 t^2 - 2 t)$.

Comment: In this kind of exercises, the first thing you should do is to draw a picture of the region of the plane you are considering. In this case it will be a triangle.
After that, you can parametrize the edges of the triangle (one by one) and then apply the transformation to the parametrizations. This will give you a parametrization of the transformed region's edges. Tag me if you have problems. :D